# Flutter - CustomPaint vs custom font

Tags: flutter

I am looking to display and scroll my own unique symbols. Each symbol is relatively simple consisting of one or more basic but non-standard shapes.

The "character set" is about 25 symbols and there might be about 100 symbols on the screen at a time.

Given the limited number of symbols, I could either render them with the CustomPaint widget or I could just create a custom font of my 25 symbols and then display them as text.

The custom font sounds like the easiest and obvious way to go, but just wondering if anyone knows of any reason not to?

Is either of the 2 methods going to be faster or more efficient on resources?